# Call polymorphic static method from a super class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, static, polymorphism

I am trying to call a static method from a parent static method.

Here is what I'd like to achieve:

```
class Parent {
    static greet() {
        console.log(self.message()) // <-- what should that be?
    }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
    static message() {
        return 'Hello, World'
    }
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
    static message() {
        return 'Hi, Everyone'
    }
}
```

My goal is to have `Child1.greet()` log `Hello, World` and `Child2.greet()` log `Hi, Everyone`.

What should I replace the `self` keyword with in the `greet()` method?

Comment: `this`.........

Comment: Well, that was unexpected! `this` in a static context‽ If you make your passive-agressive comment into a serious answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: The calling context behavior is the same as everywhere else - `Child1.greet()` will call the `greet` function with a `this` of `Child1` (even if the `greet` function is found on the prototype rather than directly on the class object being referred to)

Comment: I understand, I naively thought that JS would behave like any other language for once. Oh, JavaScript, you'll never cease to amaze and horrify me at the same time!